# Slash commands not appearing when loading them in cogs discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

When using cogs to organize slash commands, I can never get them to load.

main.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from testing import MyCog
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.command()
async def sync(ctx):
    await bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot))
    await bot.tree.sync()
    await ctx.send('Synced')

bot.run("token")
```

testing.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands
from discord import Interaction
intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        
    @app_commands.command(name = "test", description = "testing")
    async def test(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message('Hello!')
```

I don't ever get errors, but when I run the !sync command, `Synced` is sent but the slash commands never appear. I've used multiple resources, but can never figure out the correct answer. Am I putting the .sync() in the incorrect spot?

Comment: You can get the output of your synchronization, `synced = await self.bot.tree.sync()` does your app_command appear in the list when you synchronize ?

Comment: Moreover you may have a conflict with the global variable `client` defined in the global scope of `testing.py`, you don't need it. See [how to add a cog here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/pull/9157/files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By syncing globally, you'd expect them to show up in about an hour. If you want them to show up immediately for debugging or testing purposes, you should consider copying them to a guild explicitly using the [copy_global_to](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.CommandTree.copy_global_to) method of the command tree. [Example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/app_commands/basic.py#L22-L28) from `discord.py` repo.

```py
bot = commands.Bot(...)

# This is for the example purposes only and should only be used for debugging
@bot.command()
async def sync(ctx: commands.Context):
    # sync to the guild where the command was used
    bot.tree.copy_global_to(guild=ctx.guild)
    await bot.tree.sync(guild=ctx.guild)

    await ctx.send(content="Success")

@bot.command()
async def sync_global(ctx: commands.Context):
    # sync globally
    await bot.tree.sync()

    await ctx.send(content="Success")
```

If that did not solve your problems, see [My bot's commands are not showing up!](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#my-bot-s-commands-are-not-showing-up) FAQ.

By the way, you should make another command for adding cogs(or better, turn them into [extensions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/extensions.html)) and should not define another `discord.Client` or `discord.ext.commands.Bot` instance if you already have one.